# Creating a view in Struts2 to get a view of another application through URL

Tags: java, http, jakarta-ee, struts, httpurlconnection

I need to make a struts 2 application. In the one view of this app, I have to get the view of another application through the URL provided for example (http://localhost:8080/hudson/)...

Now. 
1. How to connect with the other application? (Can it be done with Apache HttpURLClient? OR any other way please guide. )

2 .If it can be done with  Apache HttpURLClient, then how to render the Response object in stuts2 framework.

Please help. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `java.net` package to resolve the issue. Example Code :

```
URL urlApi = new URL(requestUrl);
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlApi.openConnection();
httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(<requestMethod>); // GET or POST
httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
//in case HTTP POST method un-comment following to write request body
//DataOutputStream ds = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
//ds.writeBytes(body);
InputStream content = (InputStream) httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(100);
String line = null;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuilder.append(line);
}
String serverResult = stringBuilder.toString();
//now you have a string representation of the server result page
//do what you need
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I have to do the same, i`m using struts2 but i have doing a servlet.  In struts.xml you have to put  you can get the content of the url with httpauarlconnection or with httpclient (apache) and and put it at servlet response.

I have this but i have problems with the relative links of the html because it try to resolve with my domain name (the name of the servlet that make the work).